# Expand pivot table rows. Error: Unable to get the ShowDetail property of the PivotItem class

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have VBA code which runs successfully in other Excel spreadsheets. It expands row detail within a pivot table.

I tried it in a new spreadsheet and I get the error message:

> Unable to get the ShowDetail property of the PivotItem class

The only difference I can think of is that I added the data to the data model when inserting the pivot table.

```vb
Sub Expand()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim iFieldCount As Long
Dim iPosition As Long

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SubjectsAndTags")    
iFieldCount = pt.RowFields.Count - 1      
For iPosition = 1 To iFieldCount
    For Each pf In pt.RowFields
        If pf.Position = iPosition Then
            For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
                If pi.ShowDetail = False Then
                    pf.ShowDetail = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next pi
        End If
    Next pf
Next iPosition
End Sub
```

In case it helps, I recorded a macro to expand one row and this is the code it generated:

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SubjectsAndTags").PivotFields( _
      "[Query1].[SubjectName].[SubjectName]").PivotItems( _
      "[Query1].[SubjectName].&[Change Request]").DrilledDown = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation there are a couple of limitations you might be hitting:

1. "The specified range must be a single summary column or row in an outline."
2. "This property isn't available for OLAP data sources."

SOURCE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.PivotItem.ShowDetail

Try inspecting the object at runtime by setting a break-point and debugging. You can navigate objects using the `Locals` window.